# Real Admob Ads Appearing When Setting Test Mode Programmatically

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, admob

Kind of a strange issue here: Whenever I set test mode via xml, I receive the expected test ads in my emulator. However, when I try to do the same programmatically, I seem to get real ads. According to the Admob documentation, these two methods should be equivalent, no? Here is my xml code:

```
 <com.google.ads.AdView
                    android:id="@+id/adView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    ads:adSize="BANNER"
                    ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxxxx"
                    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true">
    </com.google.ads.AdView>
```

And here is the relevant Java code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
    adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);

}
```

As mentioned before, if I insert the line ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID" into the above xml code, I get the test ad just fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have to call .loadAd(adRequest) on the AdView object.

[See Google's AdMob documentation here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/android/fundamentals)

In the **Adding a com.google.ads.AdView** section.

Comment: Nice man, that worked. It turns out that if you're going to set test mode programmatically, you also need to load the ad programmatically, as you suggested. So I removed the ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" from my xml and added your code to the Java, and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to call it programmatically.

It took me a while until I get what device is AdMob's sdk what expecting cuz' I was thinking it was something related to the real device like ( adb devices )

But here is a comment from the official documentation that cleared it up.

"There will be a log message with the code needed to add the current device to the list of test devices"

You may get a message akin to it

```
I/Ads(26674): To get test ads on this device, call adRequest.addTestDevice("F1254CDFBA84BDC27F5C7C6E12445D06");
```

All you have to do after that is to place this ID into your layout xml as below

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/publisherId"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, F1254CDFBA84BDC27F5C7C6E12445D06" />
```

Hope it helps you guys out

Paulo Miguel Almeida